# Easiest way to execute a script in Visual Studio 2010 Express?

Tags: visual-studio-express, sql-scripts

I'm looking for an easy way to run an SQL file on my SQL Express from Visual Studio Express.

When not using express, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yea4bc1b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) way is nice and easy.

So far, using sqlcmd seems like my fastest option (i have a batch file for easy drag and drop purposes).

Anyone know of a neater way to update my DB from my Entity model?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just post my method in doing this, as without any other software etc, it still seems the easiest way.

```
sqlcmd -S .\sqlexpress -i "%~1"
pause
```

I made a .bat file with the above, which allows me to drag and drop .sql files and have them run against my DB.